# Bloch's Theorem validity

Tags: solid-state-physics

can someone explain me what kind of solids does Bloch's Theorem apply to? Does it only apply to crystalline solids? I mean ionic crystals should fall in this category, but what about other periodic solids?

Comment: wikipidia article on the therem says it applies to condensed matter physics  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensed_matter_physics

Comment: @annav Bloch's theorem requires periodicity. There is a lot of condensed matter that is not periodic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It applies to solids whereby you can meaningfully identify a unit cell being repeated for hundreds of such cells in any one direction, so that you can meaningfully pretend that the repetition actually goes on infinitely, and then later come back to say that it only goes for a finite size. Note that the dimensions that are not repeated will not have Bloch's theorem apply to those directions.

Crystalline solids, by definition of crystalline, necessarily will work.

There are quasiperiodic systems, and Bloch's theorem should not be working for them. I wonder if we have resident experts on them to chime in on how they are studied.

Liquids, nearer their melting points and not close to boiling point, is actually somewhat crystalline. Melting is not immediately every molecule sliding past each other, but rather is closer to entire houses worth sliding past each other. So Bloch's theorem might work well as an approximation to them.

Fully randomised, where instead of crystalline symmetry you really only have spherical symmetry, likely would not have Bloch's theorem work for them.

Comment: There is no hope of applying Bloch's theorem to liquids, even as an approximation. In the case of a finite crystal, I wouldn't say that Bloch's theorem applies to it. I would rather say that Bloch's theorem applies to an infinite periodic crystal which could be a good approximation of the finite crystal.

Comment: I specifically wrote down the conditions whereby it could be of use in those cases; and you yourself agree with them, because of the ``good approximation". Why did you even comment?

Comment: Thank you, I think that was clear enough.

Comment: "So Bloch's theorem might work well as an approximation to them." is a misleading statement. There is no use of Boch's theorem, even as an approximation,  in the case of liquids. That was the reason for my comment.

Comment: You can assert as loudly and strongly as you wish, but that which is asserted with neither evidence nor argumentation, is also dismissable without evidence nor argumentation. I at least gave the physical reason why it should work.